why does hot reload have a text glitch when loading form
hot reload flutter is working very poorly for me, I need to click on the hot reload 20 times so that the text is loaded as a result
enter image description here
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget{
  const LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF171717),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 100),
                Text(
                    "Регистрация",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                      fontSize: 36,
                      fontFamily: 'Inter', // Имя шрифта из pubspec.yaml
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, // Соответствует ExtraBold
                      letterSpacing: 36 * 0.04,
                    ),

                ),
              ]
            )
          )
      )
    );
  }
}

I tried to increase the RAM for device.
I tried doing flutter clean.
Nothing helps

I found a solution, I just changed the AVD configuration.
Changed the graphics parameter to software and everything worked!
